# How can I pipe the output of one command into another without using a large memory buffer?

Tags: powershell, pipe

I am trying to pipe the output of one command into another in powershell.  The following code below pipes the output of "xCommand" into "compressionCommand":

```
$xCommand = "C:\Python27\python.exe"
$xArgs = "arg1","arg2","arg3"

$compressionCommand = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$compressionArgs = "a", "X.gz", "-tgzip", "-siX.csv"

& $xCommand $xArgs | & $compressionCommand $compressionArgs
```

What powershell appears to be doing is storing the entire contents of the output of the first command into memory, then piping that output into the second command.  This is a problem because the output of the first command is much larger than the amount of memory the system has.

Is there any way to force powershell to actually use a pipeline instead of buffering the contents of the first command?

Comment: Does this behave the same way if you run it inside PowerShell_ISE?

Comment: @KeithHill I just verified that I see it in both Powershell and Powershell_ISE

Comment: This is pure speculation, but it might by because you call 2 external programs. Does the behavior change when you shell out to CMD like this: `cmd /c "$xCommand $xArgs | ""$compressionCommand"" $compressionArgs"`?

Comment: Have you tried putting a powershell command in the middle? Like `cmd1 | Out-Default | cmd2` or `cmd | % {$_ } | cmd2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope,

PowerShell needs to run your first command all the way through, effectively in a End block, before it can pass anything to the pipeline.  If you changed your python script to generate one item per run you could iterate through your list adding one file to your archive every time.

Although if you're diving into your python script why not do the whole operation there?  Python should even have a gzip module you can use.